# Question about Chain Rule for Partial Dervatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f(u,v)$ be a differentiable function of $u$ and $v$, where $u$ and $v$ are some function of $x$ and $y$. Then let's say $f_u(1,1)=a$ and $f_v(1,1)$= b.

Then let's say I want to find $f_x(x,y)$ at the point $(2,3)$. I will use the **chain rule**:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}  \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}  \cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

My question is, am I able to use the value $f_u(1,1)=a$ in my calculation even though it is not evaluated in the point of interest?

Comment: Your question depends on the functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$. My suspicion is that in this case just so happens that at point ($x_0,y_0)=(2,3)$ you will find that $u(2,3)=1$ and $v(2,3)=1$, and then you can use values $f_u(1,1)$ and $f_v(1,1)$.